# Strange stability issues with Matrix scale/rotation in Actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, animation, matrix, image-rotation, image-scaling

I have a Flash app where I am performing a scale and rotation operation about the center of _background:MovieClip (representing a page of a book).  I have simple event listeners on the GESTURE_ROTATE and GESTURE_SCALE events of this MC which update some variables currentRotation and currentScaleX, currentScaleY.  I then have the following code trigger on the ENTER_FRAME event of the app.

The problem I am encountering is upon rotating the MC beyond the limits of roughly 60 or -60 degrees, or scaling slightly and rotating, the MC begins to oscillate and finally spin wildly out of control and off the screen.  I've tried several things to debug it, and even tried Math.flooring the currentRotationValue and rounding the values of currentScaleX/Y to  the tenths place (Math.floor(currentScale * 10) / 10), but neither of these seems to remedy it.  I'm a little stuck at this point and have tried researching as much as I can, but couldn't find anything.  Any suggestions?  Is there an issue with doing this operation on each frame perhaps?

```
private function renderPage(e:Event) {
    var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();

    // Get dimension of current rectangle.
    var rect:Rectangle = _background.getBounds(_background.parent); 

    // Calculate the center.
    var centerX = rect.left + (rect.width/2);
    var centerY = rect.top + (rect.height/2);

    // Translating to the desired reference point.
    matrix.translate(-centerX, -centerY); 

    matrix.rotate(currentRotation / 180) * Math.PI);
    matrix.scale(currentScaleX, currentScaleY);
    matrix.translate(centerX, centerY); 

    _background.transform.matrix = matrix;
}
```

Comment: Just a thought, the getBounds() method evaluates those bounds as a vertical square, not the original dimensions.  I wonder if what you're really looking for is `.width` / `.scaleX`?

Comment: @Bradley Bossard You might want to checkout [MatrixTransformer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/motion/MatrixTransformer.html) and it's rotateAround... methods

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Thanks George for the suggestion.  I did manage to solve my problem via the response below and am in a bit of a time crunch to get it out, but I do appreciate the suggestion and will check it out in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain what behaviour you're trying to produce, but I think the problem is that `centerX` and `centerY` define the middle of `_background` in *`_background.parent`'s* coordinate space. You're then translating the `matrix` so that `_background` is rotated around the values `centerX, centerY`, but in *`_background`*'s coordinate space.

Assuming you want `_background` to rotate around a point which remains static on screen, what you actually need to do is use two different `Points`:

```
matrix.translate(-_rotateAroundPoint.x, -_rotateAroundPoint.y); 

matrix.rotate(currentRotation / 180) * Math.PI);
matrix.scale(currentScaleX, currentScaleY);

matrix.translate(_centerOnPoint.x, _centerOnPoint.y);
```

Where `_rotateAroundPoint` is the point around which `_background` should turn in it's *own coordinate space*, and `_centerOnPoint` is the point around which it should turn in its *parent's* coordinate space.

Both of those values only need to be recalculated when you want to pan `_background`, rather than every frame. For example:

```
private var _rotateAroundPoint:Point = new Point(_background.width * 0.5, _background.height * 0.5);
private var _centerOnPoint:Point = new Point(50, 50);

private function renderPage(e:Event) {
    var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();

    matrix.translate(-_rotateAroundPoint.x, -_rotateAroundPoint.y); 

    matrix.rotate((currentRotation / 180) * Math.PI);
    matrix.scale(currentScaleX, currentScaleY);
    matrix.translate(_centerOnPoint.x, _centerOnPoint.y); 

    _background.transform.matrix = matrix;
}
```

Comment: David, thanks so much.  This was obvious some bad due diligence on my part and taking from a tutorial too literally (without understanding each line).  I was in fact calculating the center of the wrong element.  By make the simple change in my code above from _background.getBounds(_background.parent); to _background.getBounds(_background); magically fixed everything.  Thanks again!